# No Console Colors in Rails Production Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

When running `./bin/rails console` locally ActiveRecord output is coloured.

However, when I access the console of the same application running on my production server (which happens to be running inside Docker), none of the output is coloured. As you can see from the screenshot below `ls` still gives coloured output, so this isn't a terminal problem.

How can I enable coloured output?

[image: terminal screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Add in your `config/environments/production.rb` this line:

```
config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true
```